# UWP sideloading requirements

Tags: uwp, certificate, authenticode, sideloading, appx

I am developing a [UWP app](https://github.com/Aftnet/LibretroRT) for distribution outside the store and outside managed environments.

I intend to create an appx package and put it on a website for direct download: users should be able to double click it and have the [App Installer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/App_Installer) do the rest, much like a traditional installer.

What do I need to do for this to happen? Is it enough to package the app with an Authenticode certificate from a CA in the default trusted store (Comodo, Symantec etc.)?

Comment: For desktop, if they are installing for the first time, leave it to the powershell script to do all the work(install certificate, turn on dev mode, install appx). From next time, App Installer can do it. For mobile, the user has to manually enable dev mode. Then download the certificate and install. And then install the appx through App Installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aby code sign certificate trusted by the target device will be good. SO comodo etc are good to go!